# Save or discard changes to mutable object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic 2 app. In it I pass around an Object `hunt` between its component. While working on it I realized `mutation` of `hunt` in one component affects the value in other components also. In a way this helps me in updating values as it changes.

There is a case where I want to discard the changes made to the object. Currently I am doing it by storing attributes in variable and reassigning it.

```
this.initLong = this.hunt.longitude;
dontSave(){
     this.hunt.longitude = this.initLong ;
}
```

I would like to know if this is the best way to do it? I see many options like `Object.create` and `clone` but this seems like the best option for my purpose.

Comment: Sorry but isn't an immutable object, by definition, not allowed to change?

Comment: sorry. my bad. i meant mutable. A simple JS object

Comment: And the reason i would like other opinion is because there are many attributes that changes. Not just ``longitude`` and there will be more once app grows.